# statistics question regarding type II errors

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

The four parts of a hypothesis test concerning a population mean from a normal population are shown below.

$H_0:  μ=50$

$H_a:  μ>50$

TS:  $Z=\dfrac{(\bar{X}−μ_0)}{(σ/√n)}$

RR:  $Z ≥ z_α$

Assume the sample size is $n=25$; $σ=7.5$ and $α=0.01$

a) Find the probability of a type II error for the alternative mean $μ_a=54$
; that is, find $β(54)$

b) Find $β(55)$
and $β(56)$

c) Repeat parts (a) and (b) for $α=0.025$

Comment: Did you find $z_{\alpha}$? What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first step is to quantify the rejection region, aka find $z_\alpha$. The easiest way to do this is to consult a [table](http://www.normaltable.com/ztable-righttailed.html), or use some software. In R, the appropriate command is `qnorm(1-0.001)` which gives us $z_\alpha \approx 2.33$. So, the rejection region solves:

$\frac{(X - 50)}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} > z_\alpha \rightarrow X > z_\alpha \sigma / \sqrt{n} + 50$. Plugging in the given parameters, we get:

$X > 53.495$.

We want to know: If the true mean is 54, what is the probability that the test statistic will be less than $53.495$ and we will fail to reject? Well, we know that in such a case the sample mean $X$ is distributed symmetrically around $54$ with a standard deviation of $\sigma/\sqrt{n} = 1.5$. So, we want to find:

$\Phi(\frac{53.495 - 54}{1.5}) = \Phi(-0.3366667)$ where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the normal distribution. You can find this using the same table as before (but you start by looking for the appropriate z-score, rather than the appropriate probability), although I used the R command `pnorm(-0.3366667)` = 0.3681841. This is $\beta(54)$.

Note that when you look for $\beta(55)$ and $\beta(56)$, the rejection region does not change, because the rejection region is a function of the null hypothesis rather than what the mean actually is. For part c of the problem, you will have to recalculate the rejection region.

Comment: Can whoever down-voted my answer please explain why? I'm new here, so if I violated some norm I'd appreciate constructive feedback.